# Five Cups for Five Imahos?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, imahot-matriarch-mothers, four-cups-wine

The Shelah [(Aseres HaDibros Pesachim Matza Ashira 102)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shenei_Luchot_HaBerit%2C_Aseret_HaDibrot%2C_Pesachim%2C_Matzah_Ashirah.4?lang=bi) writes an beautiful parallel between the four cups of Pesach and the four Imahos:

1. Sarah – Avraham and Sarah would be mekarev men and women closer to
   Hashem, transforming them to a specially chosen people as we say in
   the first kos of Kiddush: ד' אמהות הם ד' כוסות. שרה כוס ראשון,
   אשרבחר בנו מכל העמים, כי כשם אברהם אבינו בחר מהעמים וגייר את האנשים,
   כן שרהגיירה הנשים.
2. Rivkah – We start Maggid with the second cup, noting our humble beginnings as idolaters like Esav until coming
   closer to Hashem at the end as Yaakov Avinu. רבקה כוס אגדה, מתחיל
   בגנות ומסיים בשבח, וכן התחילה,מתחילה עובדי עבודה זרה ההגדה הוא עשו,
   וסיימה ביעקב ועכשיו קרבנו. וכן התחילהבגנות עבדים היינו, כי עשו הוא
   עבד לנצחיות (בראשית כה, כג) רב יעבוד צעיר. ויעקבהוא ישראל, כי שרית
   וגו' (שם לב, כט):
3. Rochel – The third kos for bentching alludes to
   Rochel who mothered Yosef, the one who fed all Klal Yisroel in Egypt.
   Moreover, she is the akeres habayis who is the source of all beracha
   in the house. רחל כוס ברכתהמזון, שיוסף בנה כלכל כל בית ישראל, והיא
   היתה עקרת. הבית ובפרק הזהב (ב"מנט, א) אין ברכה מצויה בביתו של אדם
   אלא בשביל אשתו
4. Leah – We complete Hallel on the fourth kos which
   personifies the gratitude Leah praised Hashem with for Yehuda. לאה
   ברכת השיר כוסרביעי, ופליגי בברכת השיר (פסחים קיח, א), רב יודא אמר
   יהללוך, ור' יוחנן אמר נשמתכל חי וכו', ואומר הלל הגדול כל מיני הילול
   מלאה שאמרה (בראשית כט, לה) הפעם אודהאת ה' וממנה בא נעים זמירות דמשה
   רבינו ע"ה, ולבסוף הכל אפיקומן הוא מצהשמורה סוד אמרם ז"ל (פסחים מ, א)
   בציקות של גוים אדם ממלא כריסו מהם, ובלבדשיאכל כזית מצה באחרונה

[Many](https://www.aish.com/tp/i/moha/81091867.html) [commentators](https://www.chabad.org/holidays/passover/pesach_cdo/aid/658520/jewish/What-is-the-significance-of-the-four-cups.htm) explain there is a 'fifth' cup of the Seder which parallels the fifth lashon of geulah. Following the premise of the Shelah, is there a fifth member of the Imahos who would parallel that fifth lashon of geulah?

Comment: Maybe Osnat :-) or Bat Sheva